# Verify that each given function is a solution of the given partial differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\alpha^2u_{xx}$ = $u_t$;

$u_1(x,t)= e^{-\alpha^2t}\sin x$

I took the derivate of u1 and then took the second derivate and plugged it into $\alpha^2u_{xx}$ = $u_t$ as $u_{xx}$ but it is looking really weird so I don't think I'm solving it correctly.

I found the second derivative of u1 = $\alpha^4e^{-\alpha^2t}\sin x - e^{-\alpha^2t}\sin x - 2\alpha^2e^{-\alpha^2t}\cos x$

Comment: The function $u_1$ is a function of $x$ and $t$. When you differentiate with respect to $ x$ , you take $t$ as a constant. Also When you differentiate with respect to $ t$ , you take $x$ as a constant. Look at differentiation in several variables in a Calculus book, that will answer your question with more rigor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember this is a partial derivative! When differentiating with respect to x treat t as a constant and vice versa. The product rule is not necessary in this case.

So $u_x(x,t)=e^{-\alpha^2t}\cos(x)$.

Then $u_{xx}(x,t)=-e^{-\alpha^2t}\sin(x)$.
Now let's look at the other side of the equation. 
$u_t(x,t)=-\alpha^2te^{\alpha^2t}\sin(x)$.